# PowerShell Core not recognising unicode

Tags: powershell, unicode, utf-8, powershell-core

I have a simple PowerShell Core script:

```
$Message = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PSScriptRoot\русский.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default)
$Message
```

As far as I know PowerShell Core is UTF-8 *by default*. However as you can see in the output it is actually fearing worse than PowerShell 5.1 in the unicode characters regard.

The same script runs fine on PowerShell 5.1

[image: Output]

Changing the "ReadAllText" to

```
$Message = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PSScriptRoot\русский.txt")
```

changes nothing (as it shouldn't, as it is the encoding for the read operation, but just to be clear :) ).

Comment: Can you show output of `[BitConverter]::ToString([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('E:\asd.ps1'))`?

Comment: @PetSerAl, Sure - `24-4D-65-73-73-61-67-65-20-3D-20-5B-49-4F-2E-46-69-6C-65-5D-3A-3A-52-65-61-64-41-6C-6C-54-65-78-74-28-22-24-50-53-53-63-72-69-70-74-52-6F-6F-74-5C-F0-F3-F1-F1-EA-E8-E9-2E-74-78-74-22-2C-20-5B-53-79-73-74-65-6D-2E-54-65-78-74-2E-45-6E-63-6F-64-69-6E-67-5D-3A-3A-44-65-66-61-75-6C-74-29-0D-0A-24-4D-65-73-73-61-67-65` looking for char information, I presume?

Comment: Your script file is not in UTF-8 encoding, but in codepage 1251, thus PowerShell Core (which is default to UTF-8) can not read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files does not contains characters, them contains bytes. To get characters from bytes, you need to apply some encoding. If you apply different encodings to the same bytes, then you can get different characters in the results.

Taking your byte string as a example:

```
PS> $ByteArray = [Byte[]]('24-4D-65-73-73-61-67-65-20-3D-20-5B-49-4F-2E-46-69-6C-65-5D-3A-3A-52-65-61-64-41-6C-6C-54-65-78-74-28-22-24-50-53-53-63-72-69-70-74-52-6F-6F-74-5C-F0-F3-F1-F1-EA-E8-E9-2E-74-78-74-22-2C-20-5B-53-79-73-74-65-6D-2E-54-65-78-74-2E-45-6E-63-6F-64-69-6E-67-5D-3A-3A-44-65-66-61-75-6C-74-29-0D-0A-24-4D-65-73-73-61-67-65' -split '-' | % { [Byte]::Parse($_, 'HexNumber') })
PS> [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($ByteArray)
$Message = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PSScriptRoot\�������.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default)
$Message
PS> [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1251).GetString($ByteArray)
$Message = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PSScriptRoot\русский.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default)
$Message
PS> [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString($ByteArray)
$Message = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PSScriptRoot\ðóññêèé.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default)
$Message
```

It is important to use correct encoding when reading files. And one important thing to note, is that your script file use codepage 1251, but not UTF-8. Also note that byte sequence `F0-F3-F1-F1-EA-E8-E9` (that represent world `русский` in codepage 1251) is invalid byte sequence according to UTF-8, thus you are getting seven replacement characters (`U+FFFD`) instead.

Since PowerShell Core use UTF-8 by default and your script file does not have BOM to instruct otherwise (although there are no BOM that can make PowerShell to recognize codepage 1251), PowerShell Core read your file using UTF-8 encoding, thus it is trying to access `�������.txt` (which you do not have) instead of `русский.txt`.

You can easy observe it yourself if you change your script to write file instead of reading it.

```
PS> $ByteArray2 = [Byte[]](91, 73, 79, 46, 70, 105, 108, 101, 93, 58, 58, 87, 114, 105, 116, 101, 65, 108, 108, 84, 101, 120, 116, 40, 34, 36, 80, 83, 83, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 82, 111, 111, 116, 92, 240, 243, 241, 241, 234, 232, 233, 46, 116, 120, 116, 34, 44, 32, 91, 68, 97, 116, 101, 84, 105, 109, 101, 93, 58, 58, 85, 116, 99, 78, 111, 119, 41)
PS> # Representing `[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$PSScriptRoot\русский.txt", [DateTime]::UtcNow)` in codepage 1251
PS> [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$(Convert-Path .)\write.ps1", $ByteArray2)
PS> .\write.ps1
```

Now you can read file back with your original script:

```
PS> [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$(Convert-Path .)\asd.ps1", $ByteArray)
PS> .\asd.ps1
01/18/2019 17:13:15
```

Invoking both script with PowerShell Core:

```
PS> pwsh -Command ".\write.ps1; .\asd.ps1"
01/18/2019 17:21:02
```

As you can see, your script successfully executed in PowerShell Core. If you browse current directory, then you can see, that it have both `русский.txt` and `�������.txt` in it and their content match, what was printed on console.

Actually the issue have noting to do to reading/writing files (except for script file itself). It can be demonstrated by simple script, which just print character codes of string literal:

```
PS> $ByteArray3 = [Byte[]](40, 39, 240, 243, 241, 241, 234, 232, 233, 39, 46, 71, 101, 116, 69, 110, 117, 109, 101, 114, 97, 116, 111, 114, 40, 41, 32, 124, 32, 37, 32, 84, 111, 73, 110, 116, 51, 50, 32, 36, 110, 117, 108, 108, 32, 124, 32, 37, 32, 84, 111, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 32, 88, 52, 41, 32, 45, 106, 111, 105, 110, 32, 39, 45, 39)
PS> # Representing `('русский'.GetEnumerator() | % ToInt32 $null | % ToString X4) -join '-'` in codepage 1251
PS> [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$(Convert-Path .)\test.ps1", $ByteArray3)
```

Invoking it in Windows PowerShell will yield one result:

```
PS> .\test.ps1
0440-0443-0441-0441-043A-0438-0439
```

While PowerShell Core will yield different one:

```
PS> pwsh -Command ".\test.ps1"
FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD
```

One way to deal with the issue is to use UTF-8 with BOM that ensures that both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core will use the same encoding when reading script files.

<sub>Answer is written with assuming that `[Text.Encoding]::Default.CodePage` return 1251, as it seems the case for the OP.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses a Windows-specific character encoding called cp1252. 
To use Unicode characters you need to run this command before the first time you want to do something with that file:

```
chcp 65001 | Out-Null  # set codepage to UTF-8
$Message = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PSScriptRoot\русский.txt")
```

or

```
chcp 65001 | Out-Null  # set codepage to UTF-8
$Message = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\русский.txt"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Inaccurate.  That _Windows-specific character encoding_  is called `ANSI xxxx` where `xxxx` comes from `(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage").ACP` For instance, there are `ANSI 1252` (US & Western Eu), `ANSI 1250` (Central Europe/Slavic), `ANSI 1253` (Greek), `ANSI 1251` (Cyrillic) etc. (and it isn't defined for a CJK language). `CPxxx` is so-called "OEM" Code Page (used in `cmd`) and xxx comes from `(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage").OEMCP` (respectively: CP437/850, CP852, CP737/869, CP866).